# Is the type of propositional equalities actually inductive in the HoTT context?

Tags: agda

The propositional equality type family `_==_` is defined inductively with the only constructor `idp : a == a`. But in the HoTT context it's clear that the type `A == B` may contain elements other than `idp` (after applying the postulated univalence axiom).

1. Is it correct to apply induction principle for type `A == B`? Function definitions using induction on `A == B` seem to be not total.
2. Wouldn't it be more correct to include the univalence axiom as a constructor for type `A == B` rather than have it postulated?

Comment: [Yes](http://homotopytypetheory.org/2011/04/10/just-kidding-understanding-identity-elimination-in-homotopy-type-theory/). [No](https://pigworker.wordpress.com/2015/04/01/warming-up-to-homotopy-type-theory/).